# R won't return vector

Tags: r, vector

I'm writing a program in R and I create the following vector:

```
nums <- c(224, 352, 320, 352, 352, 352, 223, 223, 352, 368, 368, 368, 368, 56, 309, 256)
```

I then print it out, like so:

```
print(nums)
```

It runs, but doesn't print anything out.  If I run it through a function, and return nums, it  prints NULL.  I tried putting just the 2 lines above into a new file and running it and it returns:

224 352 320 352 352

Earlier in the testing process, I typed into the command prompt:

```
> nums <- c(224, 352, 320, 352, 352)
> nums
[1] 224 352 320 352 352
> for(i in nums){}
> print(nums[i])
[1] NA
> for(i in nums){print(nums[i])}
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
> nums[1]
[1] 224
> nums[1:3]
[1] 224 352 320
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: 1) The loop counter `i` becomes each of the values in `nums`, meaning, `224`, then `352`, etc, and there is no element `nums[224]`, it is `NA`. 2) Your loop is **empty**: `for(i in nums){}` opens and closes the curly braces with **no instruction inside them**.

Comment: To understand what is happening, please run `for(i in nums){ print(i) }`

Comment: I'd suggest reading [this introduction to iteration in R](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html) and working it's exercises.

Comment: Tip: `for(i in seq_along(nums))`. See `help("seq_along")`.

Comment: I understand what happened with the command prompt.  I just don't understand why it won't print nums in the program I wrote...

Comment: `print(nums)` works for me on my console (i.e., it prints the vector), is there something else you aren't sharing? (`shiny`, `sink`, `knitr`, `rmarkdown`, ... do any of those have any relevance to your work environment?)

Comment: To be honest, I've never heard of any of those, so I don't think so

Comment: Figured it out...  RStudio was only running the line of code that my cursor was on

Comment: @StaceyK. Do you know you can write (and accept) an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RStudio, if you run the code using the run button, it only runs the line your cursor is on.  Do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then '<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the entire program